# ADFS reauthenticating an MVC request after a certain time period

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0

I am working on a Claims aware ASP.NET MVC application. The authentication is done via Active Directory Federation Services. The ADFS server has a time out of 8 hours. At the application level I elevated the session time out and App pool idle time to 3 hours. But still if the user was inactive for 30 min the ADFS server reauthenticates the user. Why is that happening? What do I need to set that I am not setting. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Vinita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of Powershell cmdlets for ADFS that may help you.

> Get-AdfsProperties

has a property SsoLifetime. What is it set to?

Use

> Set-AdfsProperties

to update it.

To see the full list, use

> get-command *adfs*

If you can't see the cmdlets, see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-help-using-windows-powershell%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Essentially, you need to run this cmdlet first:

> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Adfs.PowerShell

(And you normally need to run Powershell in admin. mode).

Comment: I do not have access to adfs properties since its handled by another team. The SsoLifetime is set to 8 hours according to the people who worked on it. Also it seems to work fine for other application using the same STS server. Is there any configuration I need to look harder in web.config? Or can we even manage it at the claims aware application level?

Comment: So it seems to be RP specific? Is there some kind of cookie timeout? Ask your team to run a Get-ADFSRelyingPartTrust and see what the token lifetime is for that RP?